# Modifying an array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like this

```
[ { '0': { notify_item: '1' } },
  { '1': { notify_item: '2' } },
  { '2': { notify_item: '3' } } ]
```

Now I want to replace `'0'` with some Text like `'Invoice'` and the value of that `'0'` key with value like this `{ 'sms': true,email:'false' }`.
And I want to replace every key with some text and their value with something like this `{ 'sms': true,email:'false' }`

so after replacing I want something like this

```
[ { 'Invoice': { 'sms': true,email:'false' } },
  { 'ManualReminder': { 'sms': true,email:'false' },
  { 'AutomaticReminder': { 'sms': true,email:'false' } ]
```

I am not able to understand I have tried the splice method but it is not working. Please give some hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the array using `Array.map` function. In `map` function you can use `switch` statements to match the appropriate values and return the desired output.

```js
var arr = [{
    '0': { notify_item: '1' }
  },
  { 
    '1': { notify_item: '2' } 
  },
  { 
    '2': { notify_item: '3' } 
  }];
  
var modifiedArr = arr.map(function(item) {
  var newItem = {};
  for ( var key in item) {
    var newItemKey = getKey(key);
    var newItemValue = getValue(item[key]);
  }
  newItem[newItemKey] = newItemValue;
  return newItem;
});

console.log(modifiedArr);

function getKey (key) {
  switch(key) {
    case '0':
      return 'Invoice';
    case '1':
      return 'ManualReminder';
    case '2':
      return 'AutomaticReminder';
    default:
      return 'default';
  }
}

function getValue (value) {
  switch(value.notify_item) {
    case '1':
      return { 'sms': true,email:'false' };
    case '2':
      return { 'sms': true,email:'false' };
    case '3':
      return { 'sms': true,email:'false' };
    default:
      return 'default';
  }
}
```

```html
[ { 'Invoice': { 'sms': true,email:'false' } },
  { 'ManualReminder': { 'sms': true,email:'false' },
  { 'AutomaticReminder': { 'sms': true,email:'false' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be needed to convert data, you may just get new result.
Maybe something like this will help you.

```js
var input = [ { '0': { notify_item: '1' } },
        { '1': { notify_item: '2' } },
        { '2': { notify_item: '3' } } ];
    
    
    var keyMap = {'0': 'Invoice', '1': 'ManualReminder', '2': 'AutomaticReminder'};
    
    var result = Object.keys(input).map(function (key) { 
        var item = {},
            value = input[key]; //{notify_item:'1'} for first iteration
    
        //do your logic to convert {notify_item: '1' | '2' | '3'} 
        item[keyMap[key]] = ''; //to whatever you need
        
        return item;
    });
    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

It's also harder than it should be because the structure of your data is quite weird. Wouldn't something like `{ notification_type: 0, notify_item: 1 }` be easier to work with?

Comment: No actually the above structure is for the database and it suits well but the below structure is for client so that frontend developer can understand